# Kernel of a map $\phi: \mathbb{C^*}^3 \to \mathbb{C^*}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, projective-geometry

I cannot understand which is the kernel of the following map $\phi: \mathbb{C^*}^3 \to \mathbb{C^*}^2$ with 
$$ (t_1,t_2,t_3) \mapsto \left(\frac{t_2}{t_1}, \frac{t_3}{t_1}\right) $$
In other words I do not see which elements of $ \mathbb{C^*}^3$ map to zero in $ \mathbb{C^*}^2$ under $\phi$. Of course $t_1$ cannot be because we divide by it. Therefore which ones belong to the kernel?

Note that this is the standard map induced when one tries to construct toric projective varieties.

Comment: eehm isn't it just the set $(t_1,0,0)$ , $t_1\neq 0$

Comment: Your question title (which refers to additive groups of complex numbers) no longer matches the body (which concerns multiplicative groups of non-zero complex numbers). One might take this as an object lesson for never speaking of a group as a set, but making a habit of explicitly referring to the group operation. :)

Comment: I was about to make that notice, that since we work with ${\mathbb{C}^*}^m$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$ it makes no sense to talk about elements that map to zero. Indeed, we are looking for elements that map to 1 right? I.e. the identity element of a multiplicative group. Was that the essence of your comment? By the way, I edited the title so it matches with the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the map is clearly not a map from $\mathbb C^3$ to $\mathbb C^2$, but a map from $C^3\setminus\{(0,t_2,t_3)|t_2,t_3\in\mathbb C\}$ to $\mathbb C^2$. The map is clearly undefined on $(0,1,1)$ for example.

Now, if $\phi(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ is defined, then you can find the kernel using this **hint**: $$\frac{t_2}{t_1} = 0 \iff t_2 = 0$$

Comment: Yes, and the same goes for $t_1$. I am confused with the idea though, so, is the question better phrased as: take $t_i/t_1$ for $i=2,3$ and find when this thing goes to zero? Then, the corresponding $t_i$ belongs to the kernel. Is this a right way to understand it?

Comment: @Marion No, the kernel is simply the set of elements of the domain that map to the zero element of the codomain. In your case, the zero element of the codomain is $(0,0)$, so the kernel is the set of all complex triples that map to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok, this made it more confusing. I mean, I understand what you say but why is my above statement wrong then? Find when $\phi(t_i)$ is zero and then solve this equation. The result is to find some elements of the domain that map to zero. P.S. I corrected the map to $C^*$'s

Comment: @Marion The expression "$\phi(t_i)$" makes no sense.

Comment: @Marion Also, you say "why is my above statement wrong then?". What do you mean? Which statement?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\phi(t_1, t_2,t_3)$ then. So you ask when this thing gives zero, right? Therefore you need to solve two equations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Marion Ohh, now I understand. When you said "goes to zero", I thought you said "converges to $0$". My bad. Yes, you need to solve two very simple equations.